# Validation method in zf2 forms

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework2

As an example of the form validation at the [zend framewok site](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html), it has put ‍‍‍‍`getInputFilter` into `Album` class, and uses this code for validation in the Controller :

```
$form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
```

But I put `getInputFilter` method into `AlbumForm` instead of `Album` at some modules in my project. In this case, Form class is more understandable, and you don't need to use `$form->setInputFilter(...` in Controller, and validation can be done through `isValid` method.

Why does zend framework site put `getInputFilter` in this Model?

Is it wrong that we put the `getInputFilter` into Form class?

Answer (score 0):

By having the input filters in the model they can be reused across multiple forms by calling getInputFilter. If you have an edit action and an add action with different forms you will already have to have repeated the inputfilter code twice.